# Solr: Point a directory with JSON files to index

Tags: solr, inverted-index

I just started to play around with solr. I followed the instructions in the [tutorial](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_3_1/tutorial.html) to setup solr and read the [instructions on indexing json](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateJSON) but non of these instructions clearly tell me how I can point solr to index a directory that has set of json files.

Here is the scenario:

I have a directory with avro files that I have converted into JSON in a directory. These json files actually reflect an inverted index. Here is an example:

```
{"key":"Abspielbare Disc-Formate=DVD-RW CD-RW DVD CD-R DVD-R Blu-ray DVD+R Blu-ray 3D DVD+RW","bucket":0,"itemIds":[200954633626,261238075742,300941653731,200950705778,281149811840,300938796714,321171970722,200954527166,190884779162,200954942602]}
{"key":"Accesorios=Batería Carcasa Cargador coche Funda","bucket":0,"itemIds":[111141087676]}
```

I am doing this as a prototype building (proof of concept), What is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Do you need to index these JSON files one time only, or also need to watch for changes?

Comment: @KienNguyen Just need to be one time because I am generating these files via map reduce job so there will be a pipe line to bring this data to some directory that solr can look.

Answer (score 0):

Solr would not look up the directory.
You would need to have a job to scan the directory and feed the data to Solr.
Solr does provide an interface to be fed with [JSON data](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateJSON) so you can feed the data directly through Client interface.